# Simple form with has_many through and join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, nested-attributes, has-many-through, cocoon-gem

I have models: Product, Parts and ProductParts

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_parts
  has_many :parts, through: :product_parts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_parts, allow_destroy: true
end
```

part.rb

```
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_parts
  has_many :products, through: :product_parts
end
```

product_part.rb

```
class ProductPart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The product may consist of several parts for e.g product1 = 1pcs part2 and 3pcs part 3.

I have join table: product_parts

```
  create_table "product_parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "part_id"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.index ["part_id"], name: "index_product_parts_on_part_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_parts_on_product_id"
  end
```

I would like to render simple form for new Product, where:

- I can input product name
- select parts (from all parts) and define each part quantity

I have _form.html.slim like this:

```
= simple_form_for(@product) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?
  = f.input :name
  = f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
    = f.label :part.name
    = f.input :part.quantity
  = f.button :submit
```

but it doesn't render anything. Do You have any tips how to do it in correct way?

I've also tried to do it like this:

_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@product) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
    == render 'part_fields'
  = f.button :submit
```

_part_fields.html.slim

```
= :name
= part.input :quantity
```

Server log output is:

```
17:34:21 web.1       | Started GET "/products/new" for ::1 at 2020-08-24 17:34:21 +0200
17:34:21 web.1       | Processing by ProductsController#new as HTML
17:34:21 web.1       |   Rendering products/new.html.slim within layouts/application
17:34:21 web.1       |   Part Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   CACHE Part Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
17:34:21 web.1       |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.slim:6
17:34:21 web.1       |   Rendered products/_part_fields.html.slim (Duration: 442.5ms | Allocations: 233999)
17:34:21 web.1       |   Rendered products/_form.html.slim (Duration: 449.1ms | Allocations: 240331)
17:34:21 web.1       |   Rendered products/new.html.slim within layouts/application (Duration: 451.5ms | Allocations: 242361)
17:34:21 web.1       | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 454ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 243658)
17:34:21 web.1       |
17:34:21 web.1       |
17:34:21 web.1       |
17:34:21 web.1       | ActionView::Template::Error - undefined local variable or method `part' for #<#<Class:0x00007f938cd03f28>:0x00007f938cd020b0>
17:34:21 web.1       | Did you mean?  @parts:
17:34:21 web.1       |   app/views/products/_part_fields.html.slim:2:in `view template'
```

### Thank You all for your answers. I found sample on GitHub:
[rails-recipes](https://github.com/JCesana/rails-recipes). Now I am using [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) and I am almost there where I want to be:) but:

_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@product) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  |Parts
  fieldset#parts
    = f.simple_fields_for :product_parts do |product_part|
      == render 'product_part_fields', f: product_part
      = link_to_add_association 'Add part', f, :product_parts, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'
    = f.button :submit
```

_product_part.html.slim:

```
.nested_fields.field
  = f.input :quantity
  = f.collection_select :part_id, Part.all, :id, :name
  = link_to_remove_association f
```

When form is rendered I have already two parts inputs instead of one (this should be correct).
I don't want to create new part just select parts from list and insert only quantity.
It looks like this:
[screenshot of rendered form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvOef.png)

Product is not creating, after reload form I have always fields for 2 parts more.
Here is console log:

```
12:58:14 web.1       | Started POST "/products" for ::1 at 2020-08-28 12:58:14 +0200
12:58:14 web.1       | Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
12:58:14 web.1       |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"dLVq3gUUeHnmFgVxQ7gXATOF3wdQ75a/csjmjzYN6HFrr9duoi50M4KzrSUNj/QHCrJgXO2myJPdpkybdTB0cA==", "product"=>{"name"=>"Product #1", "product_parts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"4", "part_id"=>"134", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"quantity"=>"5", "part_id"=>"168", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"quantity"=>"", "part_id"=>"266", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "3"=>{"quantity"=>"", "part_id"=>"260", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "4"=>{"quantity"=>"", "part_id"=>"262", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "5"=>{"quantity"=>"", "part_id"=>"259", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
12:58:14 web.1       |    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |   Part Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 134], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |   Part Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 168], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |   Part Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 266], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |   Part Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 260], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |   Part Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 262], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |   Part Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 259], ["LIMIT", 1]]
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
12:58:14 web.1       |    (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
12:58:14 web.1       |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:29:in `block in create'
```

What I am doing wrong with this?:

- I have two parts to choose instead of one in new rendered form
- Products and products_parts cannot be created

Comment: Can you show us where you render the partial please? Check in your server logs that it is actually being rendered, it lists the templates / partials it renders in the output

Comment: I've updated question for with your ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!:) I put working code below if somebody will have the same problem.

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_parts
  has_many :parts, through: :product_parts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, reject_if: blank?, allow_destroy: false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_parts, allow_destroy: true
end
```

product_part.rb

```
class ProductPart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :product

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :part, reject_if: all_blank
end
```

part.rb

```
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_parts
  has_many :products, through: :product_parts
end
```

products_controller.rb

```
# GET /products/new
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.product_parts.build.build_part
end
```

products/_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(@product) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?
  = f.input :name, label: false, class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('placeholders.input_product_name')
  fieldset#parts
    = f.simple_fields_for :product_parts do |product_part|
      .field
        == render 'product_part_fields', f: product_part
    = link_to_add_association 'Add part', f, :product_parts, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'
    = f.button :submit
```

products/_product_part_fields.html.slim

```
.nested-fields.field
  .field.has-addons
    = link_to_remove_association f
    .field
      = f.input :quantity
      = f.collection_select :part_id, Part.all, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'select2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The end of your server logs show that your partial is looking for a variable called 'part', and is throwing a 500 error.

Change your `_form.html.slim` file to:

```
= simple_form_for(@product) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
    == render 'part_fields', part: part
  = f.button :submit
```

This will send the part object to the partial, and clear the error.

Comment: Thank You Mark  it solved problem with server error and form is rendered but still I don't have opportunity to choose parts from parts list from db to add to them in the same time as new product.

Answer (score 0):

fields_for iterates across the association and executes the block once for every record in the association but if the association is empty there is nothing to iterate over.

So in order to show inputs for new records you need to seed the association in your controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new do |p|
      3.times { p.parts.new } 
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Also in your first attempt at the form you're using the symbol `:part` which will raise `NoMethodError (undefined method 'name' for :part:Symbol)`.

```
= f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
  = f.label :part.name
  = f.input :part.quantity
```

It should read:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :parts do |part|
  = f.label part.name
  = f.input part.quantity
```

And @marks answer addresses the missing local in your second attempt.